# Problem when iterating too many tkinter buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I need some help with my tkinter app.
The main objetive creating this app is to get the button name when it's pressed, store it in a variable and, when pressed confirm, get a dictionary with all these "string" variables stored inside. The "get buttons name" works properly, however I'm facing problems when I have too many buttons inside the interface.
The problem appear with this set of code:

I've tried cleaning the `self.list_buttons` content, without success.

when `self.list_buttons` has less than 10 values it works just fine, either when it's inside `modulo_matriz_conjunto` or `modulo_matriz_elemento`, when I have more than 10, some of the other buttons (outside this part of the code) stops working. All the button creation are made with this type of `for` loop, with `self.list_buttons` writing the text inside the button and `self.buttons_conj` which has the purpose to store the button created in the for loop. I'm wondering if this syntax are demanding too many memory of my computer and not working properly because of that. Can anyone please help me fixing this problem?

```
    def modulo_matriz_conjunto(self):
        self.font_main = ("Calibri", 9)
        self.list_buttons = ["button1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
        self.buttons_conj = []
        button_index = 0
        for name in self.list_buttons:
            if button_index < 5:
                self.conj_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line1)
            elif 5 <= button_index < 10:
                self.conj_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line2)
            elif 10 <= button_index < 15:
                self.conj_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line3)
            elif 15 <= button_index < 20:
                self.conj_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line4)
            else:
                self.conj_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line5)
            self.conj_button["text"] = name
            self.conj_button["height"] = 2
            self.conj_button["width"] = 15
            self.conj_button["bg"] = color_blue
            self.conj_button["fg"] = "white"
            self.conj_button["activebackground"] = color_dgreen
            self.conj_button["activeforeground"] = "white"
            self.conj_button["font"] = self.font_main
            self.conj_button["command"] = partial(self.func_botoes_conjunto, name)
            self.conj_button["state"] = "normal"  # normal, disabled or active
            self.conj_button.pack(side="left", expand=True)
            self.buttons_conj.append(self.conj_button)
            button_index += 1



    def modulo_matriz_elemento(self):

        self.list_buttons = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
        self.buttons_elem = []
        button_index = 0
        tk.Label(self.frame_matrix_line6, height="2").pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        for name in self.list_buttons:
            if button_index < 5:
                self.elem_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line6)
            elif 5 <= button_index < 10:
                self.elem_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line7)
            elif 10 <= button_index < 15:
                self.elem_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line8)
            elif 15 <= button_index < 20:
                self.elem_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line9)
            else:
                self.elem_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line10)
            self.elem_button["text"] = name
            self.elem_button["height"] = 2
            self.elem_button["width"] = 15
            self.elem_button["bg"] = color_blue
            self.elem_button["fg"] = "white"
            self.elem_button["activebackground"] = color_dgreen
            self.elem_button["activeforeground"] = "white"
            self.elem_button["font"] = self.font_main
            self.elem_button["command"] = partial(self.func_botoes_elemento, name)
            self.elem_button["state"] = "normal"  # normal, disabled or active
            self.elem_button.pack(side="left", expand=True)
            self.buttons_elem.append(self.elem_button)
            button_index += 1


    def func_botoes_conjunto(self, text_inside_button):
        for button in self.buttons_conj:
            button["relief"] = "raised"
            button["bg"] = color_blue
        for button in self.buttons_conj:
            if button["text"] == text_inside_button:
                button["bg"] = color_dgreen
                button["relief"] = "sunken"
        print(text_inside_button)
        self.final_information["Conjunto"] = text_inside_button
        self.modulo_matriz_elemento()

    def func_botoes_elemento(self, text_inside_button):
        for button in self.buttons_elem:
            button["relief"] = "raised"
            button["bg"] = color_blue
        for button in self.buttons_elem:
            if button["text"] == text_inside_button:
                button["bg"] = color_dgreen
                button["relief"] = "sunken"
        print(text_inside_button)
        self.final_information["Elemento"] = text_inside_button
```

Here is the full code: **EDIT2:** I forgot the class before MainFrames, here's the following code

```
class MainFrames:  # frame top, left and main3
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # main1 top frame
        self.font_main = ("Calibri", 18)
        self.frame_top = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_top.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.photo = PhotoImage(file="logo_myself.png")
        self.logo = tk.Label(self.frame_top, image=self.photo)
        self.logo["bg"] = color_blue
        self.photo.photo = self.photo
        self.logo.pack(side="left")

        self.top_name = tk.Label(self.frame_top)
        self.top_name["text"] = "Digital"
        self.top_name["bg"] = color_blue
        self.top_name["fg"] = "white"
        self.top_name["font"] = self.font_main
        self.top_name["anchor"] = "w"
        self.top_name.pack(side="left", fill="both")

        self.top_name = tk.Label(self.frame_top)
        self.top_name["text"] = "Hora a Hora FS"
        self.top_name["bg"] = color_blue
        self.top_name["fg"] = "white"
        self.top_name["font"] = self.font_main
        self.top_name["anchor"] = "w"
        self.top_name.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.top_name = tk.Label(self.frame_top)
        self.top_name["text"] = "9999"
        self.top_name["bg"] = color_blue
        self.top_name["fg"] = "white"
        self.top_name["font"] = self.font_main
        self.top_name["anchor"] = "w"
        self.top_name.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.top_name = tk.Label(self.frame_top)
        self.top_name["text"] = self.get_datatime(0) #for test only not working
        self.top_name["bg"] = color_blue
        self.top_name["fg"] = "white"
        self.top_name["font"] = self.font_main
        self.top_name["anchor"] = "w"
        self.top_name.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.top_name = tk.Label(self.frame_top)
        self.top_name["text"] = self.user_attribution(2)
        self.top_name["bg"] = color_blue
        self.top_name["fg"] = "white"
        self.top_name["font"] = self.font_main
        self.top_name["anchor"] = "e"
        self.top_name.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        # main2 left frame
        self.font_main = ("Calibri", 14)
        self.frame_left = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_left.pack(side="left", fill="y")

        self.left_name = tk.Label(self.frame_left)
        self.left_name["text"] = f"Nome: {self.get_name(0)}\n{self.user_attribution(2)} SIG"
        self.left_name["bg"] = color_blue
        self.left_name["fg"] = "white"
        self.left_name["font"] = self.font_main
        self.left_name.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        self.list_buttons = ["PAINEL PRINCIPAL", "SEGURANCA", "PESSOAS", "QUALIDADE", "MANUTENÇÃO", "PARADAS", "PRODUÇÃO"]
        for name in self.list_buttons:
            self.left_button = tk.Button(self.frame_left)
            self.left_button["text"] = name
            self.left_button["bg"] = color_blue
            self.left_button["fg"] = "white"
            self.left_button["activebackground"] = color_dgreen
            self.left_button["activeforeground"] = "white"
            self.left_button["font"] = self.font_main
            #self.left_button["command"] = self.get_datatime(0)  ###########################################
            self.left_button["state"] = "disabled"  # normal, disabled or active
            self.left_button.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        self.left_name = tk.Label(self.frame_left)
        self.left_name["bg"] = color_blue
        self.left_name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.left_button = tk.Button(self.frame_left)
        self.left_button["text"] = "HOME"
        self.left_button["bg"] = color_blue
        self.left_button["fg"] = "white"
        self.left_button["activebackground"] = color_dgreen
        self.left_button["activeforeground"] = "white"
        self.left_button["font"] = self.font_main
        #self.left_button["command"] = self.get_datatime(1)  ###########################################
        self.left_button["state"] = "disabled"  # normal, disabled or active
        self.left_button.pack(side="top", fill="both")

    def get_datatime(self, dayhour):
        self.now = datetime.now()
        if dayhour == 0:
            print(self.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
            return self.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        elif dayhour == 1:
            print(self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            return self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        else:
            print(self.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S"))
            return self.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S")

    def user_attribution(self, attibution):
        list_user = ["Digitalização", "Gestor", "Operador"]
        return list_user[attibution]

    def get_name(self, name):
        list_name = ["Rodrigo Venturi", "Joao sem braco"]
        return list_name[name]

    # def menu_buttons_def(self):
        # list_buttons = ["PAINEL PRINCIPAL", "SEGURANCA", "PESSOAS", "QUALIDADE", "MANUTENÇÃO", "PARADAS", "PRODUÇÃO"]
        # for name in list_buttons:
class Modules(MainFrames):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master=None)
        self.final_information = {"seisM": "", "Estacao": "", "Conjunto": "", "Elemento": "", "Hora Inicio": "", "Hora Fim": ""}

        self.font_main = ("Calibri", 18)
        self.frame_work = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_work.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frame_6M = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_6M.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        # de duas colunas, essa e a coluna da esquerda
        self.frame_tree = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_tree.pack(side="left", fill="both")
        self.frame_tree_top = ttk.Frame(self.frame_tree)
        self.frame_tree_top.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.frame_tree_bottom = ttk.Frame(self.frame_tree)
        self.frame_tree_bottom.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        # representa 5 linhas para matriz de botoes
        self.frame_matrix_line1 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_matrix_line1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.frame_matrix_line2 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_matrix_line2.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.frame_matrix_line3 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_matrix_line3.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.frame_matrix_line4 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_matrix_line4.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.frame_matrix_line5 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_matrix_line5.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.frame_matrix_line6 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_matrix_line6.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.frame_matrix_line7 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_matrix_line7.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.frame_matrix_line8 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_matrix_line8.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.frame_matrix_line9 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_matrix_line9.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.frame_matrix_line10 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_matrix_line10.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        # representa os frames para modulo de hora
        self.frame_time_line1 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_time_line1.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.frame_time_line2 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_time_line2.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.frame_time_line3 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_work)
        self.frame_time_line3.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        # bloco de objetos gerericos que assumem caso algum modulo nao os chame/crie
        self.open_text = tk.Text(self.frame_work)
        self.buttons = []
        self.buttons_tree = []
        self.buttons_elem = []
        self.sixM_button = None
        self.tree_button = None
        self.tree_entry = None
        self.tree_entry2 = None
        self.hour_string = None
        self.past_hour = None
        self.new_hour = None
        self.buttons_hour = []
        self.hour_button = None
        self.buttons_end = []
        self.confirm_cancel_button = None
        self.confirm_cancel_button = None
        self.conj_button = None
        self.elem_button = None
        self.buttons_conj = []


    def modulo_6M(self): # cria os botoes de 6M
        tk.Label(self.frame_6M).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.list_buttons = ["METODO", "MÃO DE OBRA", "MATERIA PRIMA", "MAQUINA", "MEDIÇÃO", "MEIO AMBIENTE"]
        self.buttons = []
        for name in self.list_buttons:
            self.sixM_button = tk.Button(self.frame_6M)
            self.sixM_button["text"] = name
            self.sixM_button["height"] = 2
            self.sixM_button["width"] = 10
            self.sixM_button["bg"] = color_blue
            self.sixM_button["fg"] = "white"
            self.sixM_button["activebackground"] = color_dgreen
            self.sixM_button["activeforeground"] = "white"
            self.sixM_button["font"] = self.font_main
            self.sixM_button["command"] = partial(self.func_botoes_6M, name)
            self.sixM_button["state"] = "normal"  # normal, disabled or active
            self.sixM_button.pack(side="left", expand=True)
            self.buttons.append(self.sixM_button)


    def modulo_arvore(self): # cria os botoes de arvore da maquina
        self.font_main = ("Calibri", 12)
        self.list_buttons = {"Prea": "pre_a.png", "Preb": "pre_b.png",
                             "Prec": "pre_c.png", "Pred": "pre_d.png",
                            "Pree": "pre_e.png", "Pref": "pre_f.png",
                             "Preg": "pre_g.png", "Preh": "pre_h.png",
                             "Prei": "pre_i.png", "prej": "pre_j.png"}
        self.buttons_tree = []
        button_index = 0
        for name in self.list_buttons:
            if button_index < 5:
                self.tree_button = tk.Button(self.frame_tree_top)
            else:
                self.tree_button = tk.Button(self.frame_tree_bottom)
            self.photo = PhotoImage(file=self.list_buttons[name]).subsample(3,3)
            self.tree_button["text"] = name
            self.tree_button["image"] = self.photo
            self.tree_button["height"] = 150
            self.tree_button["width"] = 105
            self.tree_button["bg"] = "white"
            self.tree_button["fg"] = "black"
            self.tree_button["activebackground"] = color_dgreen
            self.tree_button["activeforeground"] = "white"
            self.tree_button["font"] = self.font_main
            self.tree_button["compound"] = "top"
            self.tree_button["command"] = partial(self.func_botoes_tree, name)
            self.tree_button["state"] = "normal"  # normal, disabled or active
            self.photo.photo = self.photo
            self.tree_button.pack(side="left", expand=True)
            self.buttons_tree.append(self.tree_button)
            button_index += 1



        self.tree_entry = tk.Text(self.frame_tree)
        self.tree_entry["height"] = 6
        self.tree_entry["width"] = 50
        self.tree_entry["state"] = "disabled"
        self.tree_entry["bg"] = color_grey
        self.tree_entry.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=(0, 10), fill="both", expand=True)
        self.tree_entry2 = tk.Text(self.frame_tree)
        self.tree_entry2["height"] = 6
        self.tree_entry2["width"] = 10
        self.tree_entry2["state"] = "disabled"
        self.tree_entry2["bg"] = color_grey
        self.tree_entry2.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=(0, 10), fill="both", expand=True)

    def modulo_text_campo_aberto(self):
        self.open_text = tk.Label(self.frame_matrix_line1)
        self.open_text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, pady=40)
        self.open_text = tk.Label(self.frame_matrix_line1)
        self.open_text["text"] = "Qual a condição insegura encontrada?"
        self.open_text["font"] = self.font_main
        self.open_text["anchor"] = "w"
        self.open_text.pack(side="top", padx=10, fill="x", expand=True)
        self.open_text = tk.Text(self.frame_matrix_line1)
        self.open_text["height"] = 10
        self.open_text["width"] = 50
        self.open_text["bg"] = color_grey
        self.open_text.pack(side="left", padx=10, anchor="s", fill="both", expand=True)

    def modulo_hour_and_confirm(self):
        self.past_hour = tk.Label(self.frame_time_line1)
        self.past_hour["text"] = "Hora Inicio"
        self.past_hour["font"] = ("Calibri", 13, "bold")
        self.past_hour["anchor"] = "w"
        self.past_hour.pack(side="left", fill="x", padx=18, pady=(20,0))
        self.past_hour = tk.Label(self.frame_time_line1)
        self.past_hour["text"] = "Hora Fim"
        self.past_hour["font"] = ("Calibri", 13, "bold")
        self.past_hour["anchor"] = "w"
        self.past_hour.pack(side="left", fill="x", padx=95, pady=(20,0))

        self.hour_string = tk.StringVar()
        self.past_hour = ttk.Entry(self.frame_time_line2)
        self.past_hour["width"] = 25

        self.past_hour.pack(side="left", padx=20, fill="x")
        self.new_hour = ttk.Entry(self.frame_time_line2)
        self.new_hour["width"] = 25
        self.new_hour["textvariable"] = self.hour_string
        self.new_hour.pack(side="left", padx=20, fill="x")

        self.list_buttons = {"Hora": "clock.png"}
        self.buttons_hour = []
        button_index = 0
        for name in self.list_buttons:
            self.hour_button = tk.Button(self.frame_time_line2)
            self.photo = PhotoImage(file=self.list_buttons[name])
            self.hour_button["image"] = self.photo
            self.hour_button["height"] = 30
            self.hour_button["width"] = 30
            self.hour_button["bg"] = "white"
            self.hour_button["activebackground"] = color_dgreen
            self.hour_button["activeforeground"] = "white"
            self.hour_button["font"] = self.font_main
            self.hour_button["compound"] = "top"
            self.hour_button["command"] = self.func_refresh_datatime
            self.hour_button["state"] = "normal"  # normal, disabled or active
            self.photo.photo = self.photo
            self.hour_button.pack(side="left", expand=True)
            self.buttons_hour.append(self.hour_button)
            button_index += 1



        self.list_buttons = {"CONFIRMAR": "confirm.png", "CANCELAR": "cancel.png"}
        self.buttons_end = []
        button_index = 0
        for name in self.list_buttons:
            self.confirm_cancel_button = tk.Button(self.frame_time_line3)
            self.photo = PhotoImage(file=self.list_buttons[name])
            self.confirm_cancel_button["image"] = self.photo
            self.confirm_cancel_button["height"] = 45
            self.confirm_cancel_button["width"] = 140
            self.confirm_cancel_button["text"] = name
            self.confirm_cancel_button["bg"] = "white"
            self.confirm_cancel_button["activebackground"] = "white"
            self.confirm_cancel_button["font"] = self.font_main
            self.confirm_cancel_button["compound"] = "right"
            self.confirm_cancel_button["command"] = partial(self.func_confirm_cancel, name)
            self.confirm_cancel_button["state"] = "normal"  # normal, disabled or active
            self.photo.photo = self.photo
            self.confirm_cancel_button.pack(side="left", pady=(5,30), padx=20)
            self.buttons_hour.append(self.confirm_cancel_button)
            button_index += 1


    def modulo_matriz_conjunto(self):
        self.font_main = ("Calibri", 9)
        self.list_buttons = ["botao1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
        self.buttons_conj = []
        button_index = 0
        for name in self.list_buttons:
            if button_index < 5:
                self.conj_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line1)
            elif 5 <= button_index < 10:
                self.conj_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line2)
            elif 10 <= button_index < 15:
                self.conj_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line3)
            elif 15 <= button_index < 20:
                self.conj_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line4)
            else:
                self.conj_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line5)
            self.conj_button["text"] = name
            self.conj_button["height"] = 2
            self.conj_button["width"] = 15
            self.conj_button["bg"] = color_blue
            self.conj_button["fg"] = "white"
            self.conj_button["activebackground"] = color_dgreen
            self.conj_button["activeforeground"] = "white"
            self.conj_button["font"] = self.font_main
            self.conj_button["command"] = partial(self.func_botoes_conjunto, name)
            self.conj_button["state"] = "normal"  # normal, disabled or active
            self.conj_button.pack(side="left", expand=True)
            self.buttons_conj.append(self.conj_button)
            button_index += 1

    def modulo_matriz_elemento(self):

        self.list_buttons = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
        self.buttons_elem = []
        button_index = 0
        tk.Label(self.frame_matrix_line6, height="2").pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        for name in self.list_buttons:
            if button_index < 5:
                self.elem_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line6)
            elif 5 <= button_index < 10:
                self.elem_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line7)
            elif 10 <= button_index < 15:
                self.elem_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line8)
            elif 15 <= button_index < 20:
                self.elem_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line9)
            else:
                self.elem_button = tk.Button(self.frame_matrix_line10)
            self.elem_button["text"] = name
            self.elem_button["height"] = 2
            self.elem_button["width"] = 15
            self.elem_button["bg"] = color_blue
            self.elem_button["fg"] = "white"
            self.elem_button["activebackground"] = color_dgreen
            self.elem_button["activeforeground"] = "white"
            self.elem_button["font"] = self.font_main
            self.elem_button["command"] = partial(self.func_botoes_elemento, name)
            self.elem_button["state"] = "normal"  # normal, disabled or active
            self.elem_button.pack(side="left", expand=True)
            self.buttons_elem.append(self.elem_button)
            button_index += 1

    def func_botoes_conjunto(self, text_inside_button):
        for button in self.buttons_conj:
            button["relief"] = "raised"
            button["bg"] = color_blue
        for button in self.buttons_conj:
            if button["text"] == text_inside_button:
                button["bg"] = color_dgreen
                button["relief"] = "sunken"
        print(text_inside_button)
        self.final_information["Conjunto"] = text_inside_button
        self.modulo_matriz_elemento()

    def func_botoes_elemento(self, text_inside_button):
        for button in self.buttons_elem:
            button["relief"] = "raised"
            button["bg"] = color_blue
        for button in self.buttons_elem:
            if button["text"] == text_inside_button:
                button["bg"] = color_dgreen
                button["relief"] = "sunken"
        print(text_inside_button)
        self.final_information["Elemento"] = text_inside_button


    def func_botoes_6M(self, text_inside_button):
        for button in self.buttons:
            button["relief"] = "raised"
            button["bg"] = color_blue
        for button in self.buttons:
            if button["text"] == text_inside_button:
                button["bg"] = color_dgreen
                button["relief"] = "sunken"
        print(text_inside_button)
        self.final_information["seisM"] = text_inside_button


    def func_botoes_tree(self, text_inside_button):
        for button in self.buttons_tree:
            button["relief"] = "raised"
            button["bg"] = "white"
        for button in self.buttons_tree:
            if button["text"] == text_inside_button:
                button["bg"] = color_dgreen
                button["relief"] = "sunken"
        print(text_inside_button)
        self.final_information["Estacao"] = text_inside_button
        self.modulo_matriz_conjunto()

    def func_refresh_datatime(self):
        self.hour_now = self.get_datatime(3)
        self.hour_string.set(self.hour_now)

    def func_campo_aberto(self):
        print(self.open_text.get("1.0", "end-1c"))

    def func_confirm_cancel(self, text_inside_button):
        if text_inside_button == "CONFIRMAR":
            self.final_information["Hora Fim"] = self.hour_string.get()
            self.func_campo_aberto()
            print(self.final_information)
        else:
            self.frame_work.destroy()
            # aciona botão "painel principal"


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")
test1 = Modules(root)
test1.modulo_6M()
test1.modulo_arvore()
#test1.modulo_matriz_conjunto()
#test1.modulo_matriz_elemento()
#test1.modulo_text_campo_aberto()

test1.modulo_hour_and_confirm()
root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT2:** Sorry I forgot the first class (that goes before Modules class)

Comment: do you get error message when button stop working ? Where are these not working buttons. Show them. Maybe problem is in different place. And create minimal working code with this problem so we could easily copy code and run it to see problem.

Comment: I don't get any error, even when I try to debug the whole program. The buttons that are not working properly are outside this part of the code, I've updated the post with the rest of the code

Comment: when I run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe (without debuging) then I get error even at start because `Modules` is not tkiniter's object and it doesn't need `master` in `super().__init__()`. Later I see errors with images. Problem is that you assign all images to the same variable `self.photo.photo self.photot` but it should be `self.tree_button.photo = self.photo`. It resolves problem with bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory. After using `self.tree_button.photo = self.photo` all buttons work for me.

Comment: That `self.tree_button.photo = self.photo` helped a lot! now the pictures won't go missing anymore. It seems that the program works properly, thanks again!